# Is "Air Force One" used as an ATC call sign?

Tags: air-force-one

When the President is on an Air Force aircraft, is "Air Force One" the actual call sign used on the radio with ATC?

Comment: Very well then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [an airforce fact sheet about the airforce one fleet](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104588/vc-25-air-force-one/)

> The presidential air transport fleet consists of two specially
> configured Boeing 747-200B's — tail numbers 28000 and 29000 — with the
> Air Force designation VC-25. When the president is aboard either
> aircraft, or any Air Force aircraft, the radio call sign is "Air Force
> One."

Comment: And the [answers to another Q](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35835/why-isnt-the-presidential-747-air-force-one-heavy)  has other relevant info - like why it isn't designated Heavy

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One):

> Air Force One is the official air traffic control designated call sign for a United States Air Force aircraft carrying the president of the United States.

From FAA Air Traffic Control [document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_4.html#DjI14aJACK), Section 7.a:

> Presidential aircraft and Presidential family aircraft:
> When the President is aboard a military aircraft, state the name of the military service, followed by the word “One.”
> EXAMPLE-
> “Air Force One.”
> “Army One.”
> “Marine One.”